# Snakemake fails to produce output

Tags: output, conda, snakemake

I'm trying to run fastqc on two paired files (1.fq.gz and 2.fq.gz). Running:

*snakemake --use-conda -np newenv/1_fastqc.html*

...produces what looks like a sensible DAG:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Job stats:
job           count    min threads    max threads
----------  -------  -------------  -------------
curlewtest        1              1              1
total             1              1              1


[Sat May 21 11:27:40 2022]
rule curlewtest:
    input: 1.fq.gz, 2.fq.gz
    output: newenv/1_fastqc.html, newenv/2_fastqc.html
    jobid: 0
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

fastqc 1.fq.gz 2.fq.gz
Job stats:
job           count    min threads    max threads
----------  -------  -------------  -------------
curlewtest        1              1              1
total             1              1              1

This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```

When I run the job `snakemake --use-conda --cores all newenv/1_fastqc.html`
, the analysis runs, but the output files fail to appear. Snakemake also throws the following error:

```
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 2 of /mnt/data/kcollier/snakemake-workspace/snakefile:
Job Missing files after 5 seconds. This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait:
newenv/1_fastqc.html
newenv/2_fastqc.html completed successfully, but some output files are missing. 0
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Increasing latency does not help. The output directory I created beforehand (`newenv`) also disappears. Does anyone else know why this is?

Comment: Does executing `fastqc 1.fq.gz 2.fq.gz` in the shell yield the expected result?

Comment: Can you post the code of rule `curlewtest`?

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, it is difficult to answer precisely what causes the error. But this can happen if your shell command (or script) does not produce the output exactly as stated in the output directive of the rule - it may be something as simple as an error in the file paths.

Perhaps try to run the shell command that Snakemake runs and see if the output files, you expect, get created. You can easily see the commands that Snakemake runs by adding the --verbose/-p flag or the --debug flag to your snakemake command.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when one of the files you specified in your output is not actually generated

See "Dealing with a missing files error" for more details here:
https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/snakemake-novice-bioinformatics/03-chaining_rules/index.html